# Convert string to button

Tags: c#, string, winforms, button

I have created 5 buttons on the graphic winforms (Namely: btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4). I would like to populate an array with these buttons.

The following code is working:

```
Button[] btn = new Button[5];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
 Button[i] = new Button();

btn[0]=btn0;
btn[1]=btn1;
btn[2]=btn2;
btn[3]=btn3;
btn[4]=btn4;
```

But I would like to be able to do it inside a `for` loop (suppose that I have 100 buttons). Is this possible?

**I have tried to do it in the following way, but I get an error:**

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

```
Button[] btn = new Button[5];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    btn[i] = new Button();
    btn[i] = "btn"+i.ToString():
}
```

Comment: `btn[i].Name="btn"+i.ToString();`

Comment: What you try to do here `btn[i] = "btn"+i.ToString();`? `btn` is an array of buttons but you try save into it string. It's impossible.

Comment: omEchan please clarify. Are you trying to create an array of buttons, or a string array of the button names.

Comment: I think what he's trying to do is assign the buttons on the form to array elements  - 100 physical buttons on the form, named from `btn0` to `btn99` and an array of 100 button objects. He wants to set each array element to it's corresponding button on the form, so `btn[0] = btn0`...etc. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add your **already existing** buttons to a collection then you could use OfType extension and add them to a `List<Button>` 
(This is better than an array because you don't need to know how many buttons are present on your form)

This goes in the constructor of the form

```
public class Form1: Form
{ 
    private List<Button> myButtons = new List<Button>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
            myButtons.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

The `List<Button>` can be used like an array

```
// Get the first button in the list
Button btn = myButtons[0];

// Change the caption of the buttons....
for(int x = 0; x < myButtons.Count; x++)
     btn.Text = "Button" + x.ToString();
```

Of course you need to consider if you really need this because the form Controls collection already allows you to reach each button on your form as you can see from the first example where I have prepared the list.

Keep in mind that when you write

```
 btn[i] = new Button();
```

you are creating **dynamically** a new button replacing the instance of the button that you have set initially. This new button has nothing to do with the ones on your form designer.

Comment: I agree 100%, but i think this question has a better solution if the OP states why he is trying to achieve this, it seems like an XY problem